# Collect a specific text string from a very large text string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large text string in a column (column name: path) of a table (table name: KYC_Path). The table basically contains very large text string of image paths from which I need to extract a specific number (file number). The text strings look like this:

> F:\Original\15561 done\sohan1 15561\output_after_name_mapping\01710043429(1).jpg
>
> T:\ALL BACKUP\BACK UP 1TB(SERVER)\ALL SCANNED FILES(sohan)\01832876657 (1).JPG
>
> T:\ALL BACKUP\form 2TB passport HDD\All backup\Afren\24313\24313 Nupur_1box 651\output_after_name_mapping\01918082763(1).jpg
>
> T:\ALL BACKUP\zaman all scan\16830 noboni1 box548\output_after_name_mapping\01823152145(1).jpg

I need to collect just following numbers (file name with out the (1).jpg part), so that my new column will look like this:

> 01710043429
>
> 01832876657
>
> 01918082763
>
> 01823152145

I have already devised a method where use following formula:

```
select (right ([path],18)) as 'wallet_path', [path] into KYCPathNew
from [dbo].[KYCPath]


select (left ([wallet_path],11)) as 'wallet_path_new', [path] into KYCPathNew2
from [dbo].[KYCPathNew]
```

However that gives some issues to some rows where file name do not come correctly due to spaces between numbers (01823152145) and file extension ((1).jpg). And misses one or two characters from the file name.

Is there any other way so that I can collect all the file names more efficiently? Can I make SQL Server find the last back slash and then take 11 digits from there? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(', [Path])>0 
        THEN LEFT([Path], CHARINDEX('(', [Path])-1) 
    ELSE [Path] END [Path]
FROM(
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\', [Path])>0 THEN
            REPLACE(RIGHT([Path], CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([Path])) - 1), '.jpg', '') 
        ELSE [Path] END [Path]
    FROM 
        KYC_Path
)x
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. However it do not have only (1) in end of string. It varies.

Comment: It also gives this error: Msg 536, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: Thank you. But it gives almost same error: Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.